# How do I return 3D array to Unmaged code

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I am a new to C++. and writing a CLI wrapper to consume managed code (DLL)

```
public:array<double, 3>^ CallingBrownianManagedCode(int numPaths, int dimension, double time, int seed, array<double, 2>^ covMatrix, double stepSize, int scrambling)
    {
        std::string str = "Sobol";
        String^ newSystemString = gcnew String(str.c_str());

        Object^ result;
        result = IDevModel::RandomNumberGenerator::iBrownianBridge(numPaths, dimension, time, seed, covMatrix, stepSize, newSystemString, scrambling);
        array<double, 3>^ devArray = (array<double, 3>^) result;

        return devArray;
    }
```

I've tested the above code using CLI console app it works as desired. Now I need to expose this method to

### UnManged C++

```
__declspec(dllexport) void CallBrownianManagedAdapter()
{
   BrownianWrapper::BrownianBridgeAdapter objectBrownian;
   array<double, 3>^ brownianArray = objectBrownian.CallingBrownianManagedCodeTemp();
   return brownianArray;        
}
```

instead of void it has to be a 3d array. I tried returning manged array^, but it throws an error. 
Can you please help me? I appreciate it.

Comment: You can try returning it as a tri-dimensional SAFEARRAY of doubles, by applying the `MarshalAs` attribute to the function return (something like `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum::VT_R8)]`)

Comment: @Medinoc, Thanks for your response. I am thinking of passing the array as an argument than a return type, so it is easy to handle.

Comment: Not sure if it will be that much easier, but it shouldn't hurt.